# How to draw a line graph with data in MySQL using chart Js in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

I want to draw a line graph using the following data in MySQL table.

date - dec 10 , dec 11, dec 12, dec 13, dec 14, dec 15, dec 16, dec17, dec,18,dec 19, dec 20
attendance - 65, 58, 56, 78, 51, 54, 69, 35, 68, 43, 52

I made two queries extracting the data and stored in 2 arrays namely `$data1` and `$data2` using the code below

```
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
$myquery1 = "select date from Table_attendance";
 $query1 = mysqli_query($con, $myquery1);
 
  if ( ! $query1 ) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    die;
  }
  
  for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query1); $x++) {
  $data1[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
}


 $my1 = "select attendance from Table_attendance";
 $qu1 = mysqli_query($con, $my1);
 
  if ( ! $qu1 ) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    die;
  }
  
  for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($qu1); $x++) {
  $data2[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qu1);
}
```

I then encoded the two arrays `$data1` and `$data2` into json format using the following code.

```
$encod = json_encode($data1);
$encod2 = json_encode($data2);
```

The output of the arrays were as follows.

> [{"date":"2021-12- 10"},{"date":"2021-12-11"},{"date":"2021-12-12"},{"date":"2021-12-13"},{"date":"2021-12-14"},{"date":"2021-12-15"},{"date":"2021-12-16"},{"date":"2021-12-17"},{"date":"2021-12-18"},{"date":"2021-12-19"},{"date":"2021-12-20"}]
>
> [{"attendance ":"65"},{"attendance ":" 58 "},{"attendance ":" 56"},{"attendance":" 78 "},{"attendance ":" 51 "},{"attendance ":" 54"}{"attendance ":"69 "},{"attendance ":"35"},{"attendance":"68"},{"attendance":"43"},{"attendance ":"52"}]

Finally I tried passing the encoded values as follows to plot into a line graph but it didn't work.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
<script>

var xValues = <?php echo $encod?>;
var yValues = <?php echo $encod2?>;

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {display: true, text: 'Custom Chart Title'},
    legend: {display: false},
    
                
                
                    
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:16}}],
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Please help me with this assessment. If there is  another better code than mine please be kind enough to share.

Comment: _"but it didn't work"_ - Just saying "didn't work" doesn't give us much to go on. What actually happens? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered.

Comment: what lies behind the "it didn't work" - is there anything in the console (F12)

Comment: The json data need to be quotted in JS

Comment: @executable - You should probably be more specific here, because I honestly can't find any quoting issues in their code.

Comment: Also, I suggest to run the JS code only with sample data to confirm the data is passed correctly to the Chart Object.

Comment: What I meant from "but it didn't work" is that the graph did not displayed.

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Checked the console for errors? Checked the web page source to see if the outputted data from PHP looks ok?

Comment: @M.Eriksson Yes sir I inserted dummy values for the place of `var xValues` and `var yValues` as follows.

`var xValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` 
`var yValues = [15,16,17,18,19,20]` 

the graph came perfectly for the dummy values but didn't showed up values I passed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in an answer the problem was in encoding. In fact the array that should be passed should be in the `var xValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` format. But what I got was in `var xValues = [{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}]` format. Anyhow I will post my whole code if in case will be needed for someone in the future. Thank you very much for those who tried to help me.

The full code is as follows

```
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
// getting date column from Table_attendance table 
$myquery1 = "select date from Table_attendance";
     $query1 = mysqli_query($con, $myquery1);
 
  if ( ! $query1 ) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    die;
  }
  $a1 ="";
  for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query1); $x++) {
  $data1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
   if($a1 != ""){
      $a1 = $a1.",'".$data1['date']."'"; 
   }
else {
    $a1 = "'".$data1['date']."'";
}
}


// getting attendance column from Table_attendance table 
 $my1 = "select attendance from Table_attendance";
 $qu1 = mysqli_query($con, $my1);
 
  if ( ! $qu1 ) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    die;
  }
  $a2 ="";
  for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($qu1); $x++) {
  $data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qu1);
     if($a2 != ""){
      $a2 = $a2.",".$data2['attendance']; 
   }
else {
    $a2 = $data2['attendance'];
}
}

?>
<?php //ploting the graph  ?>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
<script>

var xValues = <?php echo '['.$a1.']'; ?>;
var yValues = <?php echo '['.$a2.']'; ?>;

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {display: true, text: 'Total attendance'},
    legend: {display: false},
    
                
                
                    
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 10, max:100}}],
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You don't need to concatenate the array in this way. Just construct the array in php and use `json_encode` to parse it in js.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass the data in the Chart Object correctly. You can transform the object in php or js.

Example in js below.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const xValues = [
    { date: "2021-12-10" },
    { date: "2021-12-11" },
    { date: "2021-12-12" },
    { date: "2021-12-13" },
    { date: "2021-12-14" },
    { date: "2021-12-15" },
    { date: "2021-12-16" },
    { date: "2021-12-17" },
    { date: "2021-12-18" },
    { date: "2021-12-19" },
    { date: "2021-12-20" },
];
const yValues = [
    { attendance: "65" },
    { attendance: "58" },
    { attendance: "56" },
    { attendance: "78" },
    { attendance: "51" },
    { attendance: "54" },
    { attendance: "69" },
    { attendance: "35" },
    { attendance: "68" },
    { attendance: "43" },
    { attendance: "52" },
];

const x = xValues.map(item => item.date);

const y = yValues.map(item => item.attendance);

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: x,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Dataset 1",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
                borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
                data: y,
            },
        ],
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: "top",
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Chart.js Line Chart",
            },
        },
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

**EDIT**
Full php example

```php
<?php

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

$myquery1 = "select date from Table_attendance";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $myquery1);

$rowsDate = mysqli_fetch_all($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$xValues = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item['date'];
}, $rowsDate);


$myquery2 = "select attendance from Table_attendance";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $myquery2);

$rowsAtd = mysqli_fetch_all($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$yValues = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item['attendance'];
}, $rowsAtd);
?>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
    const x = <?php echo json_encode($xValues) ?>;
    const y = <?php echo json_encode($yValues) ?>;

    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: x,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Dataset 1",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
                borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
                data: y,
            }, ],
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    position: "top",
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Chart.js Line Chart",
                },
            },
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
const xValues = <?php echo $encod?>;
const yValues = <?php echo $encod2?>;

const x = xValues.map(item => item.date);
const y = yValues.map(item => item.attendence);`
I tried the code as above but no graphs was output. Please bear with me I am a beginner to php and js.

Comment: @SeshanRanasinghe, Any error message in js console?

Comment: No error was displayed